# Replacing SQLyog scripts with Bash scripting

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, sqlyog

Every Monday I run scripts on SQLyog for 36 different customers (all customers use Linux servers). Running 36 scripts a day is time consuming.

I was wondering if I can create a script on Linux (running the script I always run on SQLyog) then get that output to be exported as an XML document in a certain directory. After this, I would like to schedule a Cron job to run that script and email the results to me.

This is my MySQL script that I run on SQLyog:

```
SELECT jobcard.`jobcard_number`,jobcard.`date_created`, 
   jobcard.`date_in`,jobcard.`date_completed`,em.`name` AS service_advisor,
   jobcard.`salutation`,jobcard.`name`,jobcard.`surname`,
   jobcard.`vehicle_reg`, vehicle.`make`,vehicle.`model`,vehicle.`type`,
   job_definition.`name` AS job_definition, ep.`name` AS technician, job_event.`start_event`, job_event.`end_event`
FROM jobcard
LEFT JOIN vehicle 
     ON jobcard.`vehicle` = vehicle.`id`
LEFT JOIN employee em
     ON em.`id` = jobcard.`service_advisor`
LEFT JOIN job
     ON jobcard.`id` =job.`jobcard`
LEFT JOIN job_definition
     ON job_definition.`id` = job.`job_definition`
LEFT JOIN employee ep
     ON ep.`id` =job.`technician`
LEFT JOIN job_event
     ON job.`id` = job_event.`job`
WHERE
     jobcard.`date_in` BETWEEN '2017-05-15' AND '2017-05-19'
        AND job_definition.`automatic` <>1
```

Comment: Things to learn about: 1--the `mysql` command line client. 2--linux shell scripts. 3--tab-delimited outpuf files  4--linux cron jobs.

Comment: Yep, all these are possible.

Comment: @Shadow which languages would i use ?